# Fastboot commands extremely slow

Tags: rooting, fastboot, linux, htc-u11

I'm trying to unlock my HTC U11 and I've tried to run `fastboot` both from the packages of my Ubuntu derivative (fastboot version 1:7.0.0+r33-2) and from the platform tools (fastboot version 28.0.1-4986621).

I can see my device both with `adb` in normal operation and with `fastboot devices` in download mode.

The output of `fastboot getvar all` is:

```
(bootloader) kernel: lk
(bootloader) product: htc_ocndugl
(bootloader) version: 1.0
(bootloader) max-download-size: 1562400000
(bootloader) serialno: xxx
(bootloader) slot-count: 0
(bootloader) current-slot:
(bootloader) imei: xxx
(bootloader) version-main: 1.27.401.11
(bootloader) boot-mode: download
(bootloader) version-baseband: xxx
(bootloader) version-bootloader: 1.0.0.0000
(bootloader) mid: 2PZC30000
(bootloader) cid: HTC__034
all:
finished. total time: 0.005s
```

When I try to get a token in order to unlock the phone, the command doesn't complete within any reasonable amount of time, e.g., `fastboot  oem get_identifier_token` did not complete after hours and I unplugged the phone:

```
...
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] : /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/frp
(bootloader) [KillSwitch] Last Byte is 0X01, enable unlock
FAILED (status read failed (No such device))
finished. total time: 23223.012s
```

Has anyone seen this or can give me any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same process from a different laptop and it worked instantly. I don't know what the cause of this issue is but having the alternative solution, I don't feel like investigating any longer.